sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed
I am having issues connecting my PostgreSQL database on MacOS.
My postgres.conf file is configured with -
listen_addresses = '*'      
port = 5432             
max_connections = 100

I have also tried listen_addresses = 'localhost'
My connection URI is set up as:
"postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name"

The full error I'm getting when trying to connect to the database is
OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I'm pretty new to this so any help would be much appreciated.
postgresql@14 is installed with homebrew.
I have tried brew services start postgresql@14 but get Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error. When i use brew services restart postgresql@14 that seems to work, but when checking the status with brew services list, I get Status error.

Try to start postgresql server.
Using this:
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start

Or this:
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

For more details, please see the article: How to start PostgreSQL server on Mac OS X via Homebrew.
